# Erro ao retornar dados AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Meu codigo esta funcionando até o ponto onde o ajax tem que pegar a resposta para imprimir na tela, o insert esta sendo feito normalmente no bd, caso mudo  o retorno $("#pedidos").html(data);  para $("#pedidos").html(dados); funciona retornando  serialize, alguma coisa esta me escapando?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#pedidos').submit(function(){
        var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "pedidos.php",
            data: dados,
            success: function( data )
            {
                $("#pedidos").html(data); 
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
   });
  </script>
```

abaixo a pagina php

```
   $nome = trim($_POST['nome']);
  $recado = trim($_POST['recado']);
  $error = FALSE;

  if (!$error) {
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `pedidos` (`nome`, `recado`) VALUES "
        . "( :nome, :recado)";

try {
  $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);

  // bind the values
  $stmt->bindValue(":nome", $nome);
  $stmt->bindValue(":recado", $recado);


  // execute Query
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->rowCount();
  if ($result > 0) {
    $_SESSION["errorType"] = "success";
    $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "Sua mensagem foi enviada com Sucesso.";
  } else {
    $_SESSION["errorType"] = "danger";
    $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "Falha ao enviar.";
  }
} catch (Exception $ex) {

  $_SESSION["errorType"] = "danger";
  $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = $ex->getMessage();
}
}
```

Comment: Não entendi qual é o problema.

Comment: a pagina atualiza e nao da retorno na div id="pedidos"

Comment: o data vai retornar com o que vier do pedidos.php, no código não vi o que você está querendo imprimir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que vejo você não retorna os dados em momento algum. Dá uma testada nesse código:

```
$data = array();

try {
   ...

   if ($result > 0) {
       $data["errorType"] = "success";
       $data["errorMsg"] = "Sua mensagem foi enviada com Sucesso.";
   } else {
       $data["errorType"] = "danger";
       $data["errorMsg"] = "Falha ao enviar.";
   }
} catch (Exception $ex) {
   $data["errorType"] = "danger";
   $data["errorMsg"] = $ex->getMessage();
}

echo json_encode($data);
die;
```

PS: Uma coisa que não entendi foi você colocar os retornos na $_SESSION, não seria uma boa ideia nesse caso.

Comment: olha o que retourou  = {"errorType":"success","errorMsg":"Sua mensagem foi enviada com Sucesso."} , quanto ao usso da $_session achei que era mais seguro ja que a pagina e externa

Comment: Agora você trata isso no seu JS. Você pode pegar o tipo de erro no callback do success (data.errorType) e por ai vai.